# Как внедрить OptionButton в InputBox в VBA?

Tags: vba

Задача такая: нам дан код для создания базовой анкеты. С помощью `TextBox` мы задаем количество позиций для анкеты, после чего выходит два `InputBox`, в которых спрашивают данные имени и фамилии. Проблема заключается в том, что нужно интегрировать `OptionButton`, в котором мы спрашиваем у пользователя его гражданство. Я пробовал работать непосредственно с формой, интегрировать туда не получилось, пробовал работать с кодом и внедрить еще один InputBox для этого, но он его не видит. Помогите, пожалуйста.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim X, N As Integer

N = TextBox1.Text ' Number of cells to input data

For r = 1 To N ' Loop to input data in Excel

X = X + 1

myInputBox1 = InputBox("Please type your first name:")
Application.ActiveSheet.Range("a" & X).Value = myInputBox1

myInputBox2 = InputBox("Please type your last name:")
Application.ActiveSheet.Range("b" & X).Value = myInputBox2

Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Никак, InputBox - предопределенный диалог, его нельзя никак изменить. Только создавать форму нужного вида, и ее отображать.

Comment: Так Вы же с формой работаете. Добавьте поля ввода, зачем `InputBox`?  ==В коде лишняя строка `End If`. ==Нужно указывать типы всех переменных.

Comment: Большое спасибо за помощь!